# Doesn't Spark/Hadoop support SSE-KMS encryption on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, encryption, amazon-s3

I am trying to save an rdd on S3 with server side encryption using KMS key (SSE-KMS), But I am getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400,
>   AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 695E32175EBA568A, AWS Error
>   Code: InvalidArgument, AWS Error Message: The encryption method
>   specified is not supported, S3 Extended Request ID:
>   Pi+HFLg0WsAWtkdI2S/xViOcRPMCi7zdHiaO5n1f7tiwpJe2z0lPY1C2Cr53PnnUCj3358Gx3AQ=

Following is the piece of my test code to write an rdd on S3 by using SSE-KMS for encryption:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().
  setMaster("local[*]").
  setAppName("aws-encryption")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_ACCESS_KEY)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_KEY)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.setBoolean("fs.s3a.sse.enabled", true)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "SSE-KMS")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.sse.kms.keyId", KMS_ID)

val s3a = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
val s3aName = s3a.getClass.getName
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", s3aName)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("one", "two", "three", "four"))
println("rdd is: " + rdd.collect())
rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"s3a://$bucket/$objKey")
```

Although, I am able to write rdd on s3 with AES256 encryption.

Does spark/hadoop have a different value for KMS key encryption instead of "SSE-KMS"?

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing here or doing wrong.

Environment details as follow:

- Spark: 1.6.1
- Hadoop: 2.6.0
- Aws-Java-Sdk: 1.7.4

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, It seems like existing version of Hadoop i.e. 2.8 does not support SSE-KMS :(

Following is the observation:

1. SSE-KMS is not supported till Hadoop 2.8.1
2. SSE-KMS supposed to be introduced in Hadoop 2.9
3. In Hadoop 3.0.0alpha version, SSE-KMS is supported.

Same observation w.r.t. AWS SDK for Java

1. SSE-KMS was introduced in aws-java-sdk 1.9.5

Comment: Did you ever get SSE-KMS working with Spark? If so, what are the dependencies you wound up using. It doesn't seem like the community has a fix for this AWS SSE-KMS issue till Hadoop 3.0; but the Spark community is still trying to add features for that hadoop version...

Comment: It looks like Steve Loughran answered this in a separate thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113160/how-to-write-a-spark-rdd-to-s3-using-server-side-encryption