# Issues while reading and writing a KMS encrypted spark data-frame to a S3 bucket with pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to write a Spark data-frame to AWS S3 bucket using Pyspark and getting an exceptions that the encryption method specified is not supported. The bucket has server-side encryption setup.

I'm having the following packages run from spark-default.conf: 
spark.jars.packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.5, org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0

Reviewed this existing thread: [Doesn't Spark/Hadoop support SSE-KMS encryption on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168680/doesnt-spark-hadoop-support-sse-kms-encryption-on-aws-s3) and it mentions that the above version should support SSE-KMS encryption.

I also included the core-site.xml to have the property
'fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm' set to 'SSE-KMS'

But, I still get the error.
Please note that for buckets without the SSE-KMS, this works fine.

**Error Message: AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Error Code: InvalidArgument, AWS Error Message: The encryption method specified is not supported**

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop 3.2.0 absolutely supports SSE-KMS, so whatever the problem is it'll be with: SSE-KMS key used in the config, your permissions to access it, or some other quirk (e.g. the key isn't in the same region as the bucket).

But: that release is built against AWS 1.11.375 [mvnrepo hadoop-aws](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.2.0). Mixing JARs is generally doomed. That may be a factor, it may not.

You got a 400 back from the far end, meaning something was rejected there.

Recommend

1. You look at the [troubleshooting s3a page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html)
2. Download [cloudstore](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore) and run its storediag to bootstrap connectivity diagnostics
3. try using the AWS CLI to work with data using the same setting

Note: it doesn't matter at all what the fs.s3a.encryption settings are when you are trying to read data -S3 knows the KMS key used and will automatically use it to decrypt, if you have the permissions. That's a good way to check you have read permissions on a key

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I switched the java-sdk just to 1.11.375. I ran storediag on the bucket and can see that it is able to read the files. But from spark console, when I try to do a read: spark.read.parquet('s3a://<file_location>'), I get the AWS **Error Message: Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4**. I did run the aws cli command to set the version to s3v4 and also validated from cloudstore storediag that the correct bucket-region is being picked-up. Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: the best docs see on that signing setting are: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/bk_cloud-data-access/content/s3-third-party.html , it says "AWS4SignerType" should be the right one. Try that without setting encryption and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your inputs Steve. Adding the following to the spark-defaults.conf fixed our issue:

spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm AES256