# AWS Error Message: Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, pyspark, server-side, amazon-kms

I am facing the following error while writing to S3 bucket using pyspark.

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: A0B0C0000000DEF0, AWS Error Code: InvalidArgument, AWS Error Message: Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.,

I have applied server-side encryption using AWS KMS service on the S3 bucket.
I am using the following spark-submit command -

```
spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2 --jars sample-jar sample_pyspark.py
```

This is the sample code I am working on -

```
spark_context = SparkContext()
sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context) 
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
hadoopConf = spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
#Have a spark dataframe 'source_data
source_data.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').parquet("s3a://sample-bucket")
```

Note: Tried to load the spark-dataframe into s3 bucket [without server-side encryption enabled] and it was successful

Comment: you are using a five year old copy of the s3a connector. Try using a release of spark with the hadoop-3.1 binaries and see what happens there.

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56855992/1465609

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be telling you to enable V4 S3 signatures on the Amazon SDK. One way to do it is from the command line:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4' \
    --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4' \
    ... (other spark options)
```

That said, I agree with Steve that you should use a more recent hadoop library.

**References:**

- [Amazon s3a returns 400 Bad Request with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209196/amazon-s3a-returns-400-bad-request-with-spark)