# The encryption method specified is not supported error when writing to s3 from spark job using Hadoop s3a

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, encryption

I am trying to write to s3 bucket which is KMS Server-side encrypted with a spark job running on an emr cluster.

I am passing these configs with spark-submit command:

```
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload=true",
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=XXXXXXXX",
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=XXXXXXXX",
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm=SSE-KMS",
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload=true",
"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"
```

But I am getting this error:

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The encryption method specified is not supported

Writes are working fine for AES256 encryption but with KMS it is creating the issue.

- EMR Version: emr-5.30.0,
- Spark Version: 2.4.0,
- Hadoop Version on EMR: 2.8.5,
- Aws-Java-Sdk: 1.11.835

With this link, I got to know KMS Was not supported in Hadoop till Hadoop 3.0.0: [Doesn't Spark/Hadoop support SSE-KMS encryption on AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168680/doesnt-spark-hadoop-support-sse-kms-encryption-on-aws-s3)

I tried passing external jars of `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.0.0` with spark-submit command but still same error came up.

What am I missing here or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

@Aayush Is it possible that you haven't specified the KMS key with `fs.s3a.server-side-encryption.key` ?

I am using s3 encryption with KMS keys just fine on hadoop 2.9.1 so it should work on 3.0 and likely also work on 2.8.5.